# create a nest of directories in bash

Tags: bash, directory-structure

I would like a cleaner way to nest this command;

```
if [ ! -d $BACKUPDIR ]; then
  mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR
  mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR/directories
  mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR/databases
  mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR/logs
else
  :
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With brace expansion, you could do just

```
mkdir -p "$BACKUPDIR"/{directories,databases,logs}
```

If you want to make sure the subdirectories exist, too, you can just run `mkdir` without the test. With `-p` it shouldn't complain about existing directories, and there will be no chance of the main directory `$BACKUPDIR` existing, but the subdirectories missing.

(Of course, if `BACKUPDIR` is empty, this will (try to) create the subdirectories in the file system root directory. But I'll assume you've set `BACKUPDIR` to some value earlier in the script.)

Comment: Although for best results, I suspect that the questioner should `test -n "${BACKUPDIR}"` and this answer also put it in quotes.

Comment: Yeah, the quotes should absolutely be there.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
[ -d "$BACKUPDIR" ] || mkdir -p "$BACKUPDIR"/{directories,databases,logs}
```

- `[ -d "$BACKUPDIR" ]` checks if the directory the variable `BACKUPDIR` contains exist
- `||` does short circuit evaluation, it is treated as logical OR
- The brace expansion `foo/{x,y,z}` is expanded to `foo/x foo/y foo/z` by shell